# How do i obtain a list of pdf elements

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm building my own tabletop Rpg for a pokemon game. We've gotten to the point where i'm building pdf's for pokemon. I wanted to be able to read in a pdf from a different tabletop rpg to see which elements from ITextTools so i can see how the Pdf was built so i can use it as a template for my own pdf

I have already written to pdfs and i have made a PdfReader and looked through the class for any properties that display a list but i cant find one

so far i only have

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filepath);
```

to obtain the pdf but i have no idea where the properties would be

i would like a console output to readout every property if possible.

like:

```
foreach(var item in *List of Elements*)
{
      Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's... not really how a PDF works. When you write to a PDF using iText (or any other PDF library for that matter), the elements get translated to PDF syntax. But it's hard to explain in the comment of a SO question. I invite you to use RUPS, which is a PDF diagnostic tool built on top of iText: https://itextpdf.com/en/products/rups-pdf-diagnostic-tool-reading-and-updating-pdf-syntax-debugging-pdf-code. Also have a look at the video linked at that page.

Comment: Thankyou, i'll have a look into it! guess i'll just have to design an entirely new pdf